# ERROR 1045(28000) : Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password: no )

Tags: permissions, mysql

I'm trying to install queXS cati app on my Ubuntu desktop and I installed MySQL server and PHP 5 and I cannot login into MySQL server as root without password:

```
mysql -u root
```

it says

```
ERROR 1045(28000) : Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password: no )
```

But it's okay when I enter `mysql -u root -p`

I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Try this:
mysql -u root -p mysql Enter password: and you will get: mysql>

Answer (score 54):

Add switch `-p` for password based login:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

That is the normal behaviour. You set a root password for your database so from now on you can't access it without password. That is why it reports:

> Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (**using password: no** )

Obviously when you give the password with the `-p` switch you succeed.

Answer (score 6):

In simple words your "root" session does not know the password of the mysql root user.

If you want to make it easier to access your mysql, create a file `.my.cnf` in `/root/` with these lines:

```
[mysqladmin]
 user = root
 password = mysqlrootpassword
[mysql]
 user = root
 password = mysqlrootpassword
[mysqldump]
 user = root
 password = mysqlrootpassword
```

where of course `mysqlrootpassword` is your password for mysql's root password. When you execute mysql it uses this password.

Attend to the safety of this file - give it secure rights, so that nobody on your server can read it!

Comment: It's bad to encourage others to put root passwords plaintext on disk.  By deduction, that badness property propagates to the person doing it.

Comment: During installation mysql root user's temporary password is set .
sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log

Answer (score -1):

Login to webmin and under servers, access the mySQLdatabase server.You will then be able to set the (user) password provided you have:

```
mysql -u (**user**) -p < /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-mysql-5.8.10/createDB.sql.
```

The web gui is easy but to be secure use the terminal.

cheers.

Comment: do not exists /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-mysql-5.8.10/createDB.sql.