# I installed MySQL server. but it doesn't work?

Tags: mysql

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'vindhya'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

This is the error message I got. I don't know how to log mysql.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/401449/error-104528000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-no)

Answer (score 1):

You can't access mysql with user root without using a username, this is normal behavior of mysql.

All you have is to provide the password using `-p` option

```
mysql -u vindhya -p userPassword
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have been able to set up a password while installing MySQL. Assuming you did, you should use the following syntax to log on to your server:

```
mysql -u vindhya -pyourpasswordnexttotheP -h127.0.0.1
```

If you get the same or similar error, try:

```
mysql -u vindhya -pyourpasswordnexttotheP -h127.0.0.1 --protocol=tcp
```

Answer (score 0):

At installalation mysql-server asks for a password, this is for the mysal root user,who is not identical to your systems root user. Mysql has its own users. 
Look in /etc/mysql/conf.d/debian.cnf for user debian-sys-maint user and pawword and connect with

mysql -u debian-sys-maint -p

It will ask for the password that is also in that file.